# Rails 7.0.6: Foreign key violations when trying to load fixtures, although I have commented out all fixtures I have

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures, minitest

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run my tests:

*RuntimeError: Foreign key violations found in your fixture data. Ensure you aren't referring to labels that don't exist
on associations.
*

I have commented out all fixtures I have. I have only 4 models in my app and one of them have an active storage attachment. All 4 fixture files contain only comments and still I get this error. I have tried recreating the test database and re-executed migration. I have verified all model tables are empty. And still I am getting the same error. Two commits before my tests were running fine, that is before I added 2 new models with scaffolds, one with an active storage attachment.

A note to add: one more thing changed in 2 last commits is that I have changed one of the models to have custom primary key (which is also referenced from another model). Here is the code of my models after the changes:

Update: I have the following in my Postgres logs:

```
2023-08-13 20:26:45.959 CEST [3596] ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_41320" is a system trigger
2023-08-13 20:26:45.959 CEST [3596] STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE "active_storage_variant_records" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "disbursements" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "merchants" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "merchants_files" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "orders" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "active_storage_blobs" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "active_storage_attachments" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "ar_internal_metadata" DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
2023-08-13 20:26:45.963 CEST [3596] ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_41320" is a system trigger
2023-08-13 20:26:45.963 CEST [3596] STATEMENT:  ALTER TABLE "active_storage_variant_records" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "disbursements" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "merchants" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "merchants_files" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "orders" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "active_storage_blobs" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "active_storage_attachments" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "schema_migrations" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "ar_internal_metadata" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL
2023-08-13 20:26:45.966 CEST [3596] ERROR:  permission denied for table pg_constraint
2023-08-13 20:26:45.966 CEST [3596] CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE pg_constraint SET convalidated=false WHERE conname = 'fk_rails_c3b3935057' AND connamespace::regnamespace = 'public'::regnamespace; ALTER TABLE public.active_storage_attachments VALIDATE CONSTRAINT fk_rails_c3b3935057;"
    PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 16 at EXECUTE
2023-08-13 20:26:45.966 CEST [3596] STATEMENT:  do $$
      declare r record;
    BEGIN
    FOR r IN (
      SELECT FORMAT(
        'UPDATE pg_constraint SET convalidated=false WHERE conname = ''%I'' AND connamespace::regnamespace = ''%I''::regnamespace; ALTER TABLE %I.%I VALIDATE CONSTRAINT %I;',
        constraint_name,
        table_schema,
        table_schema,
        table_name,
        constraint_name
      ) AS constraint_check
      FROM information_schema.table_constraints WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
    )
      LOOP
        EXECUTE (r.constraint_check);
      END LOOP;
    END;
    $$;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72879810/207090

Comment: Thanks, I have already reviewed this answer, but it is not of much help in my case. I have commented out all fixtures I have and still I get the error, while all tables are empty in my test DB.

Comment: I have checked pg logs and there are few errors, I will follow up with those

Comment: `permission denied` that's not supposed to happen, you should have full permissions for your test db. just drop and recreate your test database and do `RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails db:fixtures:load` then check the db logs. the point is to find the offending foreign key.

Comment: I have fully recreated the DB and still get this error. My fixture files are empty, no records are created during the fixture load. Rails seems to run some statements, which could only be executed as pg admin role and this is an issue

Comment: you need to up the privileges of your database user, for whatever reason. lots of different ways to do it, maybe something like this: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE dbname to username`

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same conclusion. I just added the superuser priviledges via UI and it worked.